# Mysql get things after certain date

Tags: mysql, database

So, I have a database table holding tickets. One of the fields is "availableUntil".

when I make the database call to get tickets, I want to be able to exclude those tickets who's date has already been passed relative to the current date.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: [MySQL - Comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: Between is for searching between dates. What he is looking for is how to check whether a date has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT blablabla... WHERE availableUntil >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [what_you_want] FROM your_base WHERE availableUntil > CURRENT_DATE();
```